# Offset interaction term

Tags: r

I want to fit a coxph model in r and offset one main effect and the interaction term.

I try to use offset command in front of the variable but it gives the error: Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(time = X, event = Delta) ~  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'offset(D:Y)')

We can generate some toy data like

```
require(survival)
D = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
Y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
X = rexp(100, 1)
Delta = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
coxph(Surv(time = X, event = Delta) ~ D + offset(Y) + offset(D:Y))
```

I want to offset Y and D:Y but it keeps giving me the error. Maybe I am wrong with how to use "offset".

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you are using the expression `D:Y` within a formula expression, it is first being processed by `offset` which does not actually "know" what to do with the ":" operator in the R formula-parsing context. It instead is giving you a warning message that implies it is being parsed as the integer-sequence operator.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(time = X, event = Delta) ~  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'offset(D:Y)')
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In D:Y : numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used
```

If you want to use the product of D and Y as an additional "interaction" offset, then you could have done this:

```
> coxph(Surv(time = X, event = Delta) ~ D + offset(Y) + offset(I(D*Y)))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time = X, event = Delta) ~ D + offset(Y) + 
    offset(I(D * Y)))

     coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z        p
D -0.9959    0.3694   0.2825 -3.525 0.000423

Likelihood ratio test=12.26  on 1 df, p=0.0004635
n= 100, number of events= 53
```

And looking at it I thought maybe even dropping the I() since offset wasn't using formula parsing logic anyway. And that proved to be the case.